# Why does Windows 8-related networking freeze up after some period of time?

Tags: networking, windows-8, sleep

I have a problem where Windows 8-related network access will cease to function, but other networking will continue working just fine. It's been very difficult for me to pinpoint this to a particular cause, but here are the clues I've gathered so far:

1. When it happens, all metro-style apps that access the network hang on startup. When this happens the event log contains an entry such as "Package Microsoft.BingNews_2.0.0.273_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe was terminated because it took too long to suspend."
2. Most desktop applications (i.e. Internet Explorer) continue to work just fine.
3. Even though it's a desktop app, Office 2013 also stops working.
4. It only seems to happen after long periods of inactivity, i.e. when the machine sits idle overnight. I've also seen it happen when the machine comes out of sleep.
5. Rebooting fixes the problem for a while.
6. When it happens, I can't restart the Network Connected Devices Auto-Setup service. It just hangs.
7. It happens on two completely different PCs, one being four years old and one that's brand new. They have completely different network adapters by different manufacturers so I suspect it's not a hardware- or driver-related issue.
8. Disabling and re-enabling the network adapter doesn't fix the problem.
9. The event log contains an entry "A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the NlaSvc service."
10. There's nothing else unusual in the event log.

Is there anything else I should be looking at? I realize that this isn't much to go on -- I'll post further clues here as I gather them.

Comment: This is probably better asked over at SuperUser.

Answer (score -1):

I would Recommend that you make sure you do a Malware Scan - and in particular look for this Service "Browser Protect"

I was able to find a tool that will scan and remove anything that might be related to that (or infected) by that Malware - [http://www.go-remove-malware.com/how-to-remove-browser-protect-hijacker/#removal tool]Go-Remove-Malware[dot]com[slash]how-to-remove-browser-protect[1]

This same Service "Browser Protect" couldn't be End Tasked - or Stopped.  I found the Install Command to remove the service - you have to look on you machine to get the actual path for your instance - but you'll get the idea.

I got the following info from the site - ShouldIRemoveIt[dot]com

3 W's[.][ShouldIRemoveIt[dot]com/BrowserProtect-10799-program[.]aspx

Open up Windows Explorer - Go to C:\ProgramData\BrowserProtect[VERSION][CONTAINER_id]\

The Website Instructions for Uninstall give this File Location: 
C:\ProgramData\browserprotect\2.5.986.67{c16c1ccb-7046-4e5c-a2f3-533ad2fec8e8}

That didn't work for Me.  My File Location was this: 
C:\ProgramData\BrowserProtect\2.6.1339.144{c16c1ccb-7046-4e5c-a2f3-533ad2fec8e8}

In my case the Version was different and the Container_ID was the same.  If might be that way for you - but I suggest copy and pasting these together with you own info.

so you'll have something like this:

C:\ProgramData\BrowserProtect\YOUR_VERSION_NUM_HERE{c16c1ccb-7046-4e5c-a2f3-533ad2fec8e8}

Once you have that info, you're ready to remove it.

Go back to your command prompt with admin priv.  enter the following command at the prompt:

"C:\ProgramData\BrowserProtect\2.5.986.67{c16c1ccb-7046-4e5c-a2f3-533ad2fec8e8}\uninstall.exe" /Uninstall /{15D2D75C-9CB2-4efd-BAD7-B9B4CB4BC693} /su

It also works without the "quotes".

Then you'll be prompted to enter a code - and once entered correctly, the services and processes will have ended and been removed.  You can then delete the whole folder.

Follup up with that Removal Tool - and you should be fine.

Thanks,